# PHP Login Script with XAMPP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, xampp

> Note: I am German. So some irrelevant text is in german like e.g. some php echo messages.

Probably it is only a beginner mistake. But I searched all night long and did not find an answer to my problem. I hope you can help me.

I want to create a php login script with XXAMP and its mysql-database.
I created a database via phpmyadmin.

[Here could be an image of this database] - But: *"You need at least 10 reputation to post images."* Sry.

Then I worked on the login.php script. It looks so:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "myname" , "mypassword")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden");
mysql_select_db("homepage") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht ausgewählt werden");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);

$abfrage = "SELECT username, password FROM access WHERE username LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis);

// $count = mysql_num_rows($ergebnis);

if($row->password == $password) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    echo "Login erfolgreich. <br> <a href=\"home.php\">Weiter</a>";
    }
else {
    echo "Benutzername und/oder Passwort waren falsch. <a href=\"index.htm\">Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

I already tested the connection to the database in a separate php file.
It works.

But when I try to login on my index.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
         <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

         <form action="login.php" method="post">
                 <input type="text" size="24" maxlength="50" name="username"<br>
                 <input type="password" size="24" maxlength="50" name="password"<br>
                 <input type="submit" value="Login">
         </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the answer on login.php:

> **password == $password) { $_SESSION["username"] = $username; echo "Login erfolgreich.
>   Weiter"; } else { echo "Benutzername und/oder Passwort waren falsch. Login"; } ?>**

I tried so much things, but nothing helped.
Maybe you have an idea why it does not work?
I would be very grateful.

Comment: It looks like your code is breaking on the `>` of `if($row->`. my guess is that php is not running, as it possibly assumes it is html code, and that is the closing tag of `<?php`.

Comment: You better get started learning techniques with PDO .. mysql_connct is out of fashion. By the time you get the hang of it, mysql_connect will be on some gravestone...  ;-)..  Look up some youtubes. They are a good start.

Answer (score 1):

try this
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
         <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

         <form action="login.php" method="post">
                 <input type="text" size="24" maxlength="50" name="username"<br>
                 <input type="password" size="24" maxlength="50" name="password"<br>
                 <input type="submit" value="Login">
         </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$verbindung = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "myname" , "mypassword")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden");
mysql_select_db("project") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht ausgewählt werden");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);

$abfrage = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username LIKE '".$username."' LIMIT 1";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
if (!$ergebnis)
{
 die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());  

 }
$row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis);

// $count = mysql_num_rows($ergebnis);

if($row->password == $password) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    echo "Login erfolgreich. <br> <a href=\"home.php\">Weiter</a>";
    }
else {
    echo "Benutzername und/oder Passwort waren falsch. <a href=\"index.htm\">Login</a>";
    }

?>
```

Note::The mysql extension is deprecated.if you are doing new project then use mysqli

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's saved as a .PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try code below:

```
<?php
session_start();?>

<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "myname" , "mypassword")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden");
mysql_select_db("homepage") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht ausgewählt werden");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);

$abfrage = "SELECT username, password FROM access WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage) or die("error");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($ergebnis);

// $count = mysql_num_rows($ergebnis);

if($row['password'] == $password) {
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
echo "Login erfolgreich. <br> <a href=\"home.php\">Weiter</a>";
}
else {
echo "Benutzername und/oder Passwort waren falsch. <a href=\"index.htm\">Login</a>";
}
?>
```

Please let me if this works or not.

Comment: Then I get following answer on login.php:  

**Weiter"; } else { echo "Benutzername und/oder Passwort waren falsch. Login"; } ?>**

Maybe I can test with some echo which information is not send/processed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

here is a complete login authentication script:

```
<?php
session_start();

//Include db connection
include 'db_connect.php';

//Get inputs and encode password to md5() remove that if no md5 enc.
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$Password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));


//Username check query
$Check_if_Username = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$Username' AND Password = '$Password'");

//Email check query
$Check_if_Mail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = '$Username' AND Password = '$Password'");


//Check if Username returns any result
if(mysql_num_rows($Check_if_Username)==1){

    //Data was found, populate variables:
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($Check_if_Username);
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $data['Username'];
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = TRUE;
}

//Otherwise, check for email match
else if(mysql_num_rows($Check_if_Mail)==1){

    //Data was found, populate variables:
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($Check_if_Mail);
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $data['Username'];
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = TRUE;

}

//No data was found:
else{
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: /login.php?error=invalid data");
    die;
}



//If the user was logged in and the data was found, close mysql connection
mysql_close();

//Then redirect
header("Location: /account.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

So I find out what was going wrong. I am embarrassed about my dumb fault.
It was not a question about programming, but the directory of opening the php files in my browser. I opened it from htdocs in xampp, but it must be done with localhost/... .
Nevertheless I am very thankful about your fast answers! I think, I should read some explaining stuff about all these programms and modules first.

See you later. Sometime I will answer some of your questions. :)